# Using bootstrap in SPFx RC.0 webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

I searched and used below code snippet:

```
 import * as React from 'react'; import styles from './Announcements.module.scss'; 
import { HttpClient, SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfigurations } from '@microsoft/sp-http'; 
import { css, Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react'; 
import SPModuleLoader from '@microsoft/sp-module-loader';


export default class Announcements extends React.Component { 
constructor(props: IAnnouncementProperties, state: IWebPartState) { 

super(props); 

SPModuleLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    }
```

WebParts are working fine but getting below error after adding 'SPModuleLoader' to constructor. I also searched about this on internet and found that many developers claimed that it works.

[image]

Comment: Are you bound to Bootstrap? Microsoft developed Fabric to replace (almost) everything Bootstrap does.

Comment: Can you share any documentation or source that I can get and use like bootstrap ?

Comment: -react is the React implementation of using Fabric **Components**, Fabric (Core / Styles) itself does what Bootstrap does: https://dev.office.com/fabric#/styles

Comment: Thats okay now I will go over on this docs, can you post this as answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: No, it is not the answer to the error you posted. some SPFx guru will answer

Comment: But answer not only solution of error its also draw the path of solution. I now changed my way to achieve purpose. But ofc its up to you.

Comment: Try the latest RC0 drop, i believe your issue seems to be related to SpModuleLoader. It's been renamed in the last couple of releases. Check your config for missing components. Sorry, not much of help. you could try looking at the release notes on what changed on the latest drop.

Comment: Also, take a look at 'sp-module-loader loadCss broken in Drop 6' : https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/286

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the BootStrap vs. Fabric conversation, here's how to load your css.

1 - In RC0, the loader changed a bit.  You need to import it as

```
import {SPComponentLoader} from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

and then reference it as

```
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

2 - Can you move the code to OnInit, rather than the constructor?  In RC0 we got rid of most of the constructor logic, and you won't have much data at all in it any more.  Something like this:

```
protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    return super.onInit();
}
```

Comment: how can I create onIit method in this class ?

Comment: Updated the original response